# Cron job isn't working

Tags: unix, web, cron

I have placed a Cron job on a page on my website. The command I have used is:

```
30 */1 * * */twitter/index.php
```

I want this page to refresh every hour starting at 12:30am (1:30am, 2:30am and so on). I have set my email so that I can receive errors and the error I get is

```
/bin/sh: 30: command not found
```

My host is "JustHost" (it does support Cron Jobs in cPanel)

The page is on:
`www.DOMAINNAME.com/twitter/index.php`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/twitter/index.php` searches the directory named `twitter` in the system root. It is very unlikely that it is there. It may be the root of your domain, but it's not the root of your website's file system directory.

Instead, it should probably be something like this:
`/home/youraccountnumber/yourdomainname/twitter/index.php`.

At least it is in my CPanel that also supports cron jobs. When I create a new cron, the part `/home/myaccountnumber` is already filled in. :)

CPanel also tells me:

```
Sample cron commands:
/usr/local/bin/php /home/*myaccount*/domains/domain.com/public_html/script.php
/usr/local/bin/curl --silent http://www.domain.com/cron.php > /dev/null
/usr/local/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cron.php
```

So, if you don't have this information, please contact your host to find out which exact path to use. They are likely to have documentation about the subject.

Comment: Perfect! The way I did it was this:

    php /home/username/public_html/cron.php 

Just putting it up there incase someone else has the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If this command:

```
30 */1 * * */twitter/index.php
```

is giving you this error:

```
/bin/sh: 30: command not found
```

then you're trying to execute it as a shell command.

To set up a `cron` command, you have to feed it to the `crontab` command. The best way to do this, IMHO, is to create a file (perhaps `$HOME/.crontab`) with properly formatted crontab entries, and then execute:

```
% crontab $HOME/.crontab
```

In other words, don't execute your crontab file, feed it to the `crontab` command.

Note also that you have to have white space between the fields. The first 5 fields specify when the command runs; the remainder is the command itself. You don't have a space between the 5th and remaining fields. Also, `*/1` is more simply written as just `*`. So this:

```
30 * * * * /twitter/index.php
```

would be the correct line to put into your crontab if you want to run `/twitter/index.php` at 30 minutes after each hour.

This assumes `index.php` is an executable file living in a directory called `twitter` at the root of your filesystem, which is possible but a bit odd. If it's somewhere else, you should specify the full path to the command you want to execute. Cron jobs run with a limited environment; in particular, they may not have the same `$PATH` you have in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

The command you should execute is the full path from root to the folder with the specific php file you want to run.  Most CPanels will have the timing settings elsewhere and will create the cron expression for you. Just put the path to the file in the command field.